# Android Intento de Multihilo en TextWatcher

Tags: java, android

Tengo en mi aplicacion un editText el cual tiene implementado en la creacion de la clase un TextWatcher

> txtBeneficiary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBeneficiary) 
>   txtBeneficiary.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        CambiarTexto(s.toString());
    }

};

  private void CambiarTexto(String s) {

        txtBeneficiary.addTextChangedListener(filter);
        String txtIngreso = s ;
        if(contactosCel.contains(txtIngreso)){

            int pos = contactosCel.indexOf(txtIngreso);
            txtBeneficiary.setText(contactos.get(pos));

        }


        txtBeneficiary.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    }
```

hasta aca todo bien , el tema es que al escribir muchas letras rapidamente , se nota que el proceso se vuelve bastante lento , hasta llegar a trancarse , investigando un poco , encontre que la mejor forma,  es ponerlo en un hilo secundario , para que el principal no se tranque , ahora intente lo siguiente

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                txtBeneficiary.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
            }
        }).start();
```

Pero no ah dado efecto , nunca use multi hilo en ningun lenguaje , por lo que cualquier detalle para resolver esto sera de mucha ayuda , desde ya gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por cada letra que escribes, le agregas un `TextWatcher` al `EditText`. En el TextWatcher tienes lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    CambiarTexto(s.toString());
}
```

Lo que a su vez el metodo `CambiarTexto(string)` agrega 2 `TextWatcher`s:

```
private void CambiarTexto(String s) {

    // agregando un TextChangedListener
    txtBeneficiary.addTextChangedListener(filter);

    ///...

    // registrado otro TextChangedListener
    txtBeneficiary.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}
```

Lo que a su vez el listener `txtBeneficiary` ejecuta el metodo `CambiarTexto(string)` y asi se repite por cada letra. Lo que significa que cuando escribes 2 veces, estas ejecutando 9 `TextWatcher`!(y puede que sean mas).

No se exactamente lo que intentas pero lo estas haciendo de la manera equivocada.

Comment: Todo esto se resume ah tenes el TEXT EDIT , y tengo un listado de numeros de telefonos , al escribirlo a mano me fijo si existe ese numero y si existe escribo el nombre de la persona envez del numero , y si no existe dejo el numero

Comment: Pero al estilo auto completar o muestras otra ventana con el nombre de la persona?

Comment: debe ser la misma , ah que me refiero  , en el mismo editbox , si ese numero que ingresaste es el mismo que existe en la lista de telefonos te meto el nombre ,